# Cast Video to TV using MediaRouteButton

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast, google-cast

I am planning to use [this](https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/Casty) small library called **"Casty"** (built upon *Google Cast V3*) to implement Video Casting functionality in my app.

I want to achieve casting YouTube video(s) just like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKjUPQCXnsM) one

Here is the code, I've copied (this should play a Video on Android TV via Chromecast via some Web based Video URL):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button playButton;
    private Casty casty;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        casty = Casty.create(this)
                .withMiniController();
        setUpPlayButton();
        setUpMediaRouteButton();
    }

    private void setUpPlayButton() {
        playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                casty.getPlayer().loadMediaAndPlay(createSampleMediaData());
            }
        });
        casty.setOnConnectChangeListener(new Casty.OnConnectChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected() {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected() {
                playButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpMediaRouteButton() {
        MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
        casty.setUpMediaRouteButton(mediaRouteButton);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        casty.addMediaRouteMenuItem(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private static MediaData createSampleMediaData() {
        return new MediaData.Builder("http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4")
                .setStreamType(MediaData.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setContentType("videos/mp4")
                .setMediaType(MediaData.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE)
                .setTitle("Sample title")
                .setSubtitle("Sample subtitle")
                .addPhotoUrl("https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png?x11217")
                .build();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I've not checked it yet, because I don't have things those are required to test Casting functionality... like *Chromecast and TV*

**My REQUIREMENT**

Instead of some `Web based Video URL`, What If I would like to *cast Youtube Video* using same lib, I hope my `code should look` like this or not:

```
return new MediaData.Builder("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKjUPQCXnsM")
```

I have two questions in my mind:

1. Shall I need to keep Play and Pause buttons (in case of YouTube video)?

**What I think:** I personally think, I do not need to use play and pause buttons separately to control media playback (because YouTube would handle this itself) - Am I right or wrong ?

2. If I am right, then where and when I need to use `createSampleMediaData()` method

So what you think How our `MainActivity.java` should look like in case of casting YouTube video?

The bad thing is, I don't have TV, otherwise, I can give many tries to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

This will be hard without testing to device, since [android tv emulator cannot be use to test the cast functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011968/can-the-android-tv-emulator-in-android-studio-recieve-casts). You can check out this document about [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers), to be familiar about the Cast API functionalities. You may also want to check this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22790045/5995040) that talks about playing web videos to cast API. There is also a document about what are the list of [video formats](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media) that are supported.

Hope this helps.